# how to print all duplicate (same contents) files from a given directory?

Tags: python, file, compare, hashtable

I'm kind of new in Python and this is the first time I'm trying to wright a script.
I need to go over a given directory and print out all the duplicated files (files with same contents). If there are to sets of duplicated files then I need to print them in different lines.

Anyone have an idea?

Comment: This is not a suitable problem for a first script. I suggest that you start with simpler things and come back to this in a month or so.

Comment: I know, but still I have to do this.. I do have basic knoledge in python just need help.
I was thinking of creating a dictionary with a file size as a key and a list of the files with that size as the value. After I'm done I was planing to run over the dict and compare only files with same size in order to save time.. and print out if I find duplicated files.

Is it doable or maybe there is a better simpler way?
Thanks

Comment: Ok. If you know enough Python to get a list of the files in a given directory and to store the file sizes and names in a dictionary, then I guess you have the skills to write this program.

Comment: FWIW, Wikipedia has a large [List of duplicate file finders](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_duplicate_file_finders), both Open Source (in various languages, including Python) and commercial.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, creating a dictionary with the file size as the key and a list of all the files with that size as the value, and then only comparing files of the same size is a good strategy. However, there's another step you can take to improve the efficiency.

Once you've identified your lists of files of the same size, rather than laboriously comparing each pair of files in the list byte by byte (and returning as soon as you find a mis-match), you can compare their [digital fingerprints](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fingerprint_%28computing%29).

A fingerprinting algorithm (also known as a message digest) takes a string of data and returns a short string of bytes that is (hopefully) unique to that input string. So to find duplicate files you just need to generate the fingerprint of each file and then see if any of the fingerprints are duplicates. This is generally a *lot* faster than actually comparing file contents, since if you have a list of fingerprints you can easily sort it, so all the files with the same fingerprint will be next to each other in the sorted list.

With the usual functions used for fingerprinting there is a tiny probability that two files with the same fingerprint aren't actually identical. So once you've identified files with matching fingerprints you still do need to compare their byte contents. However, in those *very* rare cases where two non-identical files have matching fingerprints the file contents will generally differ quite radically, so such false positives can be quickly eliminated.

The odds of two non-identical files have matching fingerprints is so tiny that unless you have many thousands of files to de-dupe you can probably skip the first step of grouping files by size and just go straight to fingerprinting.

The Wikipedia article on fingerprinting I linked to above mentions the [Rabin fingerprint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabin_fingerprint) as a very fast algorithm. There *is* a 3rd-party Python module available for it on PyPI - [PyRabin 0.5](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyRabin/0.5), but I've never used it.

However, the standard Python [hashlib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/hashlib.html) module provides various secure hash and message digest algorithms, eg [MD5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5) and the SHA family, which are reasonably fast, and quite familiar to most seasoned Python programmers. For this application, I'd suggest using an algorithm that returns a fairly short fingerprint, like `sha1()` or `md5()`, since they tend to be faster, although the shorter the fingerprint, the higher the rate of collision. Although MD5 isn't as secure as once thought it's still ok for this application, unless you need to deal with files created by a malicious person who's creating non-identical files with the same MD5 fingerprint on purpose.

Another option if you expect to get lots of duplicates files is to compute two different fingerprints (eg both SHA1 and MD5) - the odds of two non-identical files have matching SHA1 and MD5 fingerprints is microscopically tiny.

FWIW, here's a link to a simple Python program I wrote last year (in an answer on the Unix & Linux Stack Exchange site) that computes the MD5 and SHA256 hashes of a single file. It's quite efficient on large files. You may find it helpful as an example of using hashlib.

[Simultaneously calculate multiple digests (md5, sha256)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/163769/88378)